# Django on Apache with FCGI

Tags: django, apache, fastcgi

**Solved:** Unfortunately I wasn't able to solve the problem but I started over and followed the [Django + FastCGI guide](http://wiki.asmallorange.com/HOWTODjangoFastCGI) on the ["A Small Orange" wiki](http://wiki.asmallorange.com/Welcome) and everything is working as expected.

I am trying to setup Django with FCGI on Apache. The web hosting plan that I am using is A Small Orange's shared hosting plan.

Django is installed, working and is able to create database tables when I run the syncdb command. If I run `manage.py runserver` and then use lynx to navigate to `localhost:8080` django will correctly display. However, It is not possible to view django over the internet as the page displays a 500 internal server error.

I have the flup python package installed and am using python version 2.6.

The following is the contents of my .htaccess file that is situated in `/public_html/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^(media/.*)$ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^(admin_media/.*)$ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^(dispatch\.fcgi/.*)$ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [L]
```

The following is the contents of my dispatch.fcgi file that is also located in `/public_html`:

```
#!/usr/local/lib/python2.6
import sys
import os
os.chdir('/home/thegamer/django/projects/thegamer')
sys.path += ['/home/thegamer/django/django']
sys.path += ['/home/thegamer/django/projects']
from fcgi import WSGIServer
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'thegamer.settings'
WSGIServer(WSGIHandler()).run()
```

Comment: And what does the error log say?

Comment: [Sun Nov 08 11:52:42 2009] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/home/thegamer/public_html/dispatch.fcgi" has failed to remain running for 30 seconds given 3 attempts, its restart interval has been backed off to 600 seconds

Comment: What happens if you try to run dispatch.fcgi manually?  If it works, it should just wait for for requests.  If it terminates, it's probably with a message explaining what went wrong.

Comment: It output the expected HTML code. I have solved the problem but unfortunately am not entirely sure what was causing the problem. I'll try and find out and update when I have. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting again and following the [Django + FastCGI guide](http://wiki.asmallorange.com/HOWTODjangoFastCGI) on the ["A Small Orange" wiki](http://wiki.asmallorange.com/Welcome) resulted in everything working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Are you  using sqlite? If so, you need an absolute path for the db file, not a relative.

If thats not it, set DEBUG=True in your settings and let django tell you what it is.

Comment: I am using mysql and the problem isn't with my database. The problem occurs somewhere between apache recieving the request and it being passed to django to handle. Running django locally works fine so no errors are produced. Running it over the internet causes problems and I cannot access it to view what the error messages would be.

Comment: As an alternative, it is possible to use email notification for getting the debug infos see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648349/common-errors-when-moving-a-django-app-from-dev-to-prod/1648578#1648578

Comment: It's more probably some environmental difference between you running the manage command and apache running the server than an error before reaching django (or if the error is before django, there is probably something usefull in the default error log of apache). So enable debugging (or email-on-error, but then you also need to make sure that mail from the server can actually reach you) and check the error message.

Comment: (Ignore previous message, didn't see your quote of the actual error message above)

Answer (score 1):

I just had this exact same problem. It took some time but I was *finally* able to resolve it with assistance from A Small Orange’s (very helpful!) support guys.

You need to make sure that your `dispatch.fcgi` file is `chmod`’ed to 755. Anything else (mine was 775) will cause this error.