# Is there any way to host django project with xampp?

Tags: django, apache, xampp

I was trying to deploy it on apache24 lounge
I was wondering if it is passible

Comment: If possible, go for the easiest route. If you're on Windows; there's Waitress for hosting; on linux there is Gunicorn, and Nginx as a proxy. It will be way easier. Is there a particular reason you wish to deploy with xampp?

Comment: It is Apahache2.4, notxampp

Comment: This will likely help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696308/django-on-apache-with-fcgi